# Avoid .NET extension methods for number datatypes?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Let's say I'd like to add an extension method called **IsOdd()** to the number datatypes in .NET.  The implementation of this, however, will be virtually the same for the datatypes like **Int16**, **Int32**, **Int64**, etc., except for the parameter being defined for the extension method.  I really don't like this redundancy but wonder if there's no way to avoid it.

Is there a better way to handle this?  Should I instead, say, implement an extension method for System.Math and create overloaded definitions for **IsOdd()**?  In short, I'm curious if extension methods for the number datatypes should generally be avoided altogether, due to their inherent redundancy.

Comment: Well, I'd avoid putting an extension method on those types simply because they are so commonly used, an I wouldn't need `IsOdd` all that often.  It would be cluttering them up.

Comment: ... to add to @Servy's comment, it's generally considered bad practice to add extension methods to very general types like struct & object. Instead just create a static class and test with `MyMath.IsOdd(x)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot create an extension method for a static class.
The closest you can do, is the following:

```
public static bool IsOdd<T>(this T number) where T : struct
```

This will restrict the extension method to value types.
However, you'll still get some stuff you can't deal with (e.g. `DateTime` for example). You'll have to throw an exception in this case.

**Edit:** As Mangist said in the comments, you can do the following to further constrain the method:

```
 public static bool IsOdd<T>(this T number) 
     where T : struct, IComparable, IComparable<T>, 
               IConvertible, IEquatable<T>, IFormattable
```

Comment: So you want to clutter up intellisense for every single struct loaded in your assembly.  Sounds like it's more trouble than it's worth at that point.

Comment: You can constrain it down further by adding where T : struct, 
          IComparable, 
          IComparable<T>, 
          IConvertible, 
          IEquatable<T>, 
          IFormattable

Comment: @Servy, it depends what your point is. Also remember that you can control whether a method is displayed using a `using` statement, and using the `[EditorBrowsable]` attribute.

Comment: If you use `[EditorBrowsable]` then you won't see it even when you want to, and it won't do you all that much good.  If it was just adding it to all of the types that it actually should `int16`, `int32`, `int64`, etc., even when it's only there via a `using` at the top, it's still going to show up a *lot*.  I don't know about you, but I don't have a whole lot of non-trivial classes that don't use some sort of numeric type at some point.  Add in all of the non-numeric structs that would be affected on top of that and I know it would be more work that it would save in my mind.

Comment: @Servy, okay, okay, fine. You win. If it really bothers you that much, you don't *have* to define it. Personally, I could see myself doing something like this (though I don't know about `IsOdd()`).

Comment: @RichK That has already been mentioned in the comments here, and I have already responded to it.

Comment: I like this solution, and it's working great for me so far.  The one caveat is what @Servy points out, how you end up potentially adding the extension methods to a lot of other classes that match the constraints of T.  Should that be a problem for a given solution, then jamietre's comment at the top regarding setting up a custom Math class would probably work best.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine `Generics` with extension methods to avoid duplications, like in the case you mentioned. e.g

`IsOdd<Type>()`